# Dynamic propery shows false to isset but very next line echos a value

Tags: php, object, properties

I a bit confused here. I need to throw an exception when a value of an object is not set, however it throws my exception regardless of if it is or is not set.

I run

```
var_dump(isset($this->{$idName}));
var_dump($this->{$idName});
```

and the results are

```
bool(false) 
string(1) "1"
```

I would expect the first to be true. Am I missing something obvious?

To clairfy, I am trying to check if the property of the object that is stored in `$idName` is set. In this case `$idName = "id"`
So `$this->id` is what I'm checking.

`$this->id` will be retrieved from __get()

Comment: Are you sure `$this->id` exists and isn't accessed via `__get()`?

Comment: Have you created a magic __isset() method in your class? or only a magic __get() method?

Comment: ah, yes, it is coming from __get().. That must be my issue. Good, call, if you set an answer, I'll accept, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the magic `__isset()` method.

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    return isset($this->data[$name]);
}
```

Change according to where you store the data.

From the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset):

> __isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties.

Answer (score 0):

If this property is private/protected, and if you are trying to access its value directly from outside using $this->property syntax, make sure it's not just comming from your class __get() magic method.